# Cron urls get a 403 status on Flexible Environment

Tags: google-app-engine, google-managed-vm, app-engine-flexible

We are experimenting with Flexible Environment and we want to migrate an existing application. Everything seems to go well except from cron entries.

We have a bunch of cron and every url is secured as admin" (as stated in the documentation), but every time the url is hit by the cron service we get a 403 status, if the url is hit by the user via browser everything works well.

On standard environment everything is good.

Is there anything we can check about?

Comment: This might be related to a similar issue with PubSub push endpoints. You can track progress here:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35904120

At the moment it doesn't seem like they are moving fast enough on this.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you add `login: admin` in app.yaml handler section to secure cron service on Google App Engine standard environment.

But on App Engine flex, it changed how to secure your cron handlers like this (PHP example):

Check $_SERVER['HTTP_X_APPENGINE_CRON'] and if it's true, the requests are coming from App Engine cron service.